# Invalid mail alert

Tags: aix, mail-command

When I log in to Unix, I get new mail alert:

```
[YOU HAVE NEW MAIL]
```

I checked my mail and I don't have any:

```
$ mail
Mail [5.2 UCB] [AIX 5.X]  Type ? for help.
"/var/spool/mail/userId": 0 messages
No mail
```

How to prevent invalid mail alerts?

Comment: What happens if you run `ls -l /var/spool/mail`? Is there a file with your account name listed?

Comment: Do $MAIL or $MAILPATH contain the pathname of a file that exists and has a mod time more recent than access time?  $MAILPATH may contain a colon-separated list of files.